# Multiple Layer hidden layer in LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

```
x = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim,))

# LSTM encoding
h = LSTM(2048)(x)
```

This is few lines of code from the file I downloaded from the internet. I think `h` holds for single layer LSTM layer with 2048 units. How can it make it multi layer i.e 2 hidden layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another layer (lets call it `g`)! But since we are passing to another `LSTM` layer, we're going to have to add `return_sequences` keyword parameter to the first layer so that we can get the right input shape to the second layer.

```
x = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim,))

# LSTM encoding
h = LSTM(2048, return_sequences=true)(x)
g = LSTM(10)(h)
```

Comment: Thanks you, it worked! I just have a query I tried      h = Sequential()
    h.add(LSTM(2048, input_shape=(timesteps, input_dim), return_sequences=True))
    h.add(LSTM(2048)).. I tried this but it created errors in in references code.

Comment: check this link https://github.com/TulsiJain/keras_lstm_vae/blob/master/lstm_vae/vae.py I need to modified line 36 to make it multilayer as h = Sequential() h.add(LSTM(2048, input_shape=(timesteps, input_dim), return_sequences=True)) h.add(LSTM(2048)).. then It throws the https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IqiKliWhj4u-SNcUN4h1T7G94CbFFbiCCe6dZHTzHBs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: that code uses the functional api (like the example above).  From that error it seems like you may be mixing the sequential and functional model building styles in a incorrect way. Can you post a sample of what you're doing (update your question)